# How do I edit a system file when I am root user but I receive "you are not in the sudoers file"?

Tags: 12.04, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 12.04(LTS) 64 bit. I have edited `/etc/group` and added my username `erfan` in front of `vboxusers` as following:

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
.
.
.
erfan:x:1000:
sambashare:x:124:
debian-xfs:x:125:
vboxusers:x:126:erfan
vboxsf:x:127:
guest-59wkHG:x:128:
```

After this change, I can not use the `sudo` command and I receive following message:

```
"erfan is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."
```

I can not install any package and manage my operating system.

I think if I can find a way to delete my user name `erfan` from in front of `vboxusers`, then this problem will be resolved.

Could you give me an idea to delete it and edit the `group` file? Or any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: When logged as **erfan**, what is the output of running the command `id` ?

Comment: Did you change something else in the file `/etc/group`? Did you remove your username from in front of `sudo:x:27`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with root login (no sudo)

in your terminal you should simply input `su -`
it will ask you the **root** password, not the **erfan**'s one

after that edit your file

Comment: But unfortunately (or fortunaly, it's a question of point of view), the root user doesn't have a password, so `su -` will not succeed.

Comment: Hmmm not on a stock Ubuntu system; there is no root password. It would be `sudo su` and you do need erfan's sudo password.

Comment: so the alternative solution would be using a Live CD, right?

Comment: Yes. The question is though, why did he suddenly lose `sudo` privileges from editing `/etc/group`?